# Map value get removed

Tags: map

I have a map `conIdVisitRecord_map` with parameter `id` and `string` inside `map_customSet` loop and I am populating map `conIdVisitRecord_map`. Here I am able to put the record but every time a new record comes old record get removed. But I am not able to understand why this happens. Is there anybody have any idea to solve this issue. 
My code :

```
//Map to hold all the custom setting records
Map<String, ContactVisitObjectsMapping__c> map_customSet = new Map<String, ContactVisitObjectsMapping__c>(); 
//Map to hold the contact Id and custom setting Visit field name
Map<Id, String> conIDField_map = new Map<Id, String>();
Map<Id, String> conIDField_map_clone = new Map<Id, String>();
//Map to hold the conatct Id and Visit records 
Map<Id, CVSR__Visit__c> conIdVisitRecord_map = new Map<Id, CVSR__Visit__c>();



for(CVSR__Visit__c v: Trigger.new){

    // get all the redords from custom setting 
    map_customSet = ContactVisitObjectsMapping__c.getAll();

    //getting all the fields from CVSR__Visit__c
    Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = SObjectType.CVSR__Visit__c.fields.getMap();

    // loop through all the custom setting records 
    for(String fieldName : map_customSet.keyset()){
        system.debug('field Name ' + fieldName );

        if(map_customSet.get(fieldName).Active__c == true){

            //converting the fieldname in string format to SObjectField               
            SObjectField sObjfieldName = (SObjectField) fieldMap.get(fieldName); 

            system.debug('new value ' + v.get(sObjfieldName));
            system.debug('old value ' + System.Trigger.oldmap.get(v.id).get(sObjfieldName));
            system.debug('field Name with active ' + fieldName);


            // verifying the old and new value                  
            if(v.get(sObjfieldName) != System.Trigger.oldmap.get(v.id).get(sObjfieldName)){
                //Populating map 
                system.debug('sObjfield Name in old new map ' + sObjfieldName );


                conIDField_map.put(v.CVSR__Contact__c, string.valueof(sObjfieldName));
                conIdVisitRecord_map.put(v.CVSR__Contact__c, v.clone());


                system.debug('con Id Visit Record map ' + conIdVisitRecord_map);
                system.debug('con ID Field map Record map ' + conIDField_map);
                system.debug('con ID Field map Record map clone ' + conIDField_map_clone );

            }

        }


    }

}

//When the field on Visit is updated 
if(Trigger.isUpdate){
    //creating the var for ContactVisitObjectsUpdate_ctrl  class and passing the map value to a ContactVisitObjectsUpdate_isUpdate method
    ContactVisitObjectsUpdate_ctrl cvUpdate = new ContactVisitObjectsUpdate_ctrl();
    system.debug('conID Field map before add ' + conIDField_map );
    system.debug('conId Visit Record map before add ' + conIdVisitRecord_map );
    cvUpdate.ContactVisitObjectsUpdate_isUpdate(conIDField_map, conIdVisitRecord_map );

}
}
```

Comment: Without your code we can't be able to help you !

Comment: Can you also update the question to have the correct map names. Map A and Map B are not in your code.

Comment: yes I have updated my question and also added code to it.

Comment: If the CVSR__Visit__c objects have a common parent ID stored in the CVSR__Contact__c field then later ones will replace earlier ones. One way around that is to change `Map<Id, CVSR__Visit__c>` to be `Map<Id, List<CVSR__Visit__c>>` (and ass the list the first time a key is used) but there may be better approaches.

Comment: I have the same issue, any updates?